# Modeling nested data in Google data studio community connectors

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

My general question is: **how should I model the data / build a schema to support nested fields (lists of primitives, lists of objects)**, like:

```
{
 "id": 123,
 "phrases": ["a", "b", "c"],
 "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Jon"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob"
    }
 ]
}
```

In general, I'd expect two solutions:

**1. De-normalize the data. Duplicate rows for each nested value/attribute**

```
"rows": [
    {
      "values": [123, "Jon", "a"]
    },
    {
      "values": [123, "Jon", "b"]
    },
    {
      "values": [123, "Jon", "c"]
    },
    ...   
]
```

Probably I could do it by myself but just wondering if there is a way google data studio does it for me? I know that tools like Power BI allow expanding nested types.

**2. Normalize the data. Create multiple tables and build relations between them.**

Is it possible in Google data studio? Are there any examples and documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your use case for the data. I would recommend going for #1.

You have the option to send multiple schema/tables through one data source from a Community Connector but you cannot send the relationship information. I don't know of any documentation available on this yet.